# Has the proof theoretic ordinal of $MLTT + M$ been studied?

Tags: ordinals, proof-theory, type-theory, ordinal-analysis

By $MLTT + M$ I mean basic Martin Lof type theory with general $M$-types. It well known that the proof-theoretic ordinal of $MLW$ (MLTT with W-types) is the Bachmann-Howard ordinal, but is the proof theoretical ordinal of the analogous theory $MLTT + M$ known?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20161208192016/http://benedikt-ahrens.de/publications/TYPES2015_Ahrens_Capriotti_Spadotti.pdf), in $MLTT$ $M$-types may actually be constructed from $W$-types, so the answer is: Probably not, and simply because adding $M$-types to the language does not add any power to $MLTT$, since $M$-types are already expressible in $MLW$.

It would be an interesting question to see how far this generalizes to other types of inductive an coinductive constructions, see my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162512/to-what-extent-are-final-coalgebras-simply-a-conceptual-tool-in-light-of-a-the) for something along those lines, but from the recentness of this article, this is probably somewhat of an open/active research project.